# Is Transit visa required for Doha layover?

Tags: visas, transit, qatar

My fiance is traveling from Dubai back to the USA with a layover in Doha, Qatar for two hours.

Does he need a Transit visa?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Transit Visa in Doha, Qatar](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/48463/transit-visa-in-doha-qatar)

Comment: No, you don't. Even if you did, US citizens are granted visa-on-arrival.

Comment: @AleksG We can't close questions as duplicate of duplicates.

Answer (score 4):

> No.  There is no requirement to hold a visa while in transit at Doha International Airport.

Source: http://support.qatarairways.com/entries/20456948-Do-I-need-a-visa-for-transiting-in-Doha-

Comment: Do you have a source? A link? Something more than your single sentence? It's been flagged as a low-quality answer, so it'd be awesome if you could extend it.

Comment: This should probably be a comment.

Comment: Just wondering when/why you would put the answer as a comment, and when as an answer?

Comment: [The help centre has a page on answering, that you might want to read.](http://travel.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer). Personally I draw the line at one-liner answers which just say `yes` or `no` without providing a reputable source to back this claim up where necessary. Doing so means asking the reader to take the word of a stranger as ultimate truth, and I find that hard to do. IMHO posts like this should either be comments or shouldn't even exist on SE sites. We aim for quality here. Having said this your answer now has a source as Mark suggested.

Comment: Should you wish to further improve this answer you could provide more context to the source link by, for example, quoting it's relevant parts.