# Transit Visa in Doha, Qatar

Tags: transit-visas, qatar

If you're traveling on a US passport leaving Dubai returning to the USA with a 2 hour layover changing planes in Doha, Qatar, do I need a Transit Visa?

Comment: Not only is it a duplicate, its the same exact person with the same exact question.

Answer (score 2):

No, you don't. Even if you did, US citizens are granted visa-on-arrival.

Source: Been to Doha many many times.

Comment: Okay ChromoZoneX...it seems like you are an expert on Qatar laws and policies. Answer me this: If someone completed a job in Dubai, went through immigration in Doha, Qatar, who issues the job completion certificate to clear customs if that person was paid a large sum of money for completing the job? Thanks

Comment: @user30130 Sorry, I don't have experience with that stuff.