# Do I need a transit-visa for a layover in Qatar?

Tags: indian-citizens, transit-visas, qatar

I would be in transit in Qatar for 24 hours, I have read answers where it is said that transit visa is not required. For [example](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/48456/is-transit-visa-required-for-doha-layover) and couple of other duplicates, but both the duplicates were for people traveling on US passports, while I'll be traveling on Indian passport. Hence just to know/ensure that there is no hassle.

Also if somebody knows the embassy/consulate/visa people's e-mail which could help in clarification for the same.Somebody whom you could write to and their word would be final.

Comment: What do you mean by visa e-mail ?

Comment: The link in the dupe you link to is quite clear. "There is no requirement to hold a visa while in transit at Doha International Airport." If you want a more authoritative answer you will certainly not find it here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [Qatar Airways website](http://support.qatarairways.com/hc/en-us/articles/206466228-Do-I-need-a-visa-for-transiting-in-Doha-):

> No.  There is no requirement to hold a visa while in transit at Doha International Airport.

This applies to citizens of all countries.