# Transit Visa in Doha

Tags: visas, transit, doha

I am studying in Moscow.I am about to return to Vietnam from Moscow and will transit in Doha.Is Transit visa required for Doha layover?

Comment: Duplicate of [Is Transit visa required for Doha layover?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/48456/is-transit-visa-required-for-doha-layover)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the official MOI [website](https://portal.moi.gov.qa/qatarvisas/visadetails.html?ctr=190&res=142) and [Qatar Airways'](https://qatarairways.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/206466228-Do-I-need-a-visa-for-transiting-in-Doha-), no one needs a visa to transit (i.e stay within international zone) through DOH.

But, if you want to go in the country, you can qualify for a specific Transit visa if :

- You fly in **and** out of DOH on Qatar Airways
- Your layover is more than 5h

If you qualify and the visa (that is obtained through Qatar Airways) is issued, you'll get a *up to* 96h entry visa

Answer (score 1):

Most probably you won't need a Transit visa but it also depends on how long is your layover. If your layover is longer than 24hrs then there might be different conditions specific to your country.